# MPMoviePlayerController not showing scrubber on fast networks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

when using an MPMoviePlayer instance inline to stream a remote mp3 file, the scrubber is replaced with the label "Streaming..." when on "fast" networks (like 3G or WiFi).

The ControlStyle is set to MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded.

On slow connections like Edge, the scrubber shows.

This is compiled for iOS 5, tested with iOS 6.
Anyone else experiencing that, too?

Is there a way to always show the scrubber and not show just "Streaming..."?

Thanks, Jan

Comment: Sounds like your M3U8 is incorrectly setup. Tried a different stream, e.g. Apple's streaming example http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

Comment: Till, that doesn't exactly tell me anything, since the inline view is only designed to have enough space to hold the audio playback controls. The video works, as does the mp3, yet a scrubber isn't available for both.

Comment: I am sorry, I skipped the fact that you were using an MP3 and not http streaming... hence my comment does not make any sense. Sorry.

Comment: Till, no problem. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: To anyone interested: This might depend on the HTTP-Header sent by the server on answer. If Accept-Ranges: bytes is not set (HTTP-RFC 14.5) MPMoviePlayerController seems to fall back to "it's not available" rather then what is suggested in the HTTP RFC (it's considered available, except for if the server forbids it). I'm looking into this and will provide an answer when i've explored this enough. My thought is that on slow connections, the player falls back to downloading the file completely which reanables searching on the file (since it is now locally available).